# Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\xi+i\eta,z_2,\ldots,z_n)e^{i[t_1(\xi+i\eta)+t_2z_2+\cdots+t_nz_n]}d\xi$ is independent of $\eta$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Show that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\xi+i\eta,z_2,\ldots,z_n) e^{i[t_1(\xi+i\eta) + t_2z_2+\cdots+t_nz_n]} \, d\xi$$ is independent of $\eta$, for arbitrary real $t_1,\cdots,t_n$ and complex $z_1,\cdots,z_n$, where $f$ is an entire function that satisfies $$|f(z)| \le \gamma_N (1+|z|)^{-N} e^{r|\operatorname{im}z|}$$

This is needed to prove the Paley-wiener Theorem (for this I am following the book of Rudin's Functional Analysis). The argument in the book goes something like this:

To see this , Let $\Gamma$ be a rectangular path in $(\xi+i\eta)$ plane, with one edge on the real axis, one on the line $\eta=\eta_1$, whose vertical edges move off to infinity(What does it mean??). By Cauchy's Theorem the integral of the integrand over $\Gamma$ is $0$. (for this the rectangle has to be closed right?? If the edges move off to infinity, how come it is closed??). By the second condition , the contribution of the vertical edges to this integraltend to $0$. (How??).

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I suppose it just means that you take a rectangle with a side determined by the points $(x,y_1), (x,y_2)$, and letting $x\to \infty$.

Comment: We consider a finite rectangle $[-R,R] \times [-\xi,\xi]$. "whose vertical edges move off to infinity" That simply means taking $R\to\infty$. We can estimate the integral over the edges for a finite $R$ and show that as $R\to\infty$ this contribution goes to zero. "for this the rectangle has to be closed right?" Yes that is true.

Comment: The integrals over the two edges are $\int_{z=R}^{z=R+i\xi} f(z){\rm d}z$ and $\int_{z=-R}^{z=-R+i\xi} f(z){\rm d}z$ respectively. You can estimate this using the [estimation lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) using the given estimate for $|f(z)|$.

Comment: @Winther got it.. Thank you

Comment: Another way is to differentiate the w.r.t $\eta$ under the integral (justified by Lebesgue's theorem), using the Cauchy-Riemann equation $\partial_\xi +i\partial_\eta$ and calculating the integral of $\partial_\xi$ with the fundamental theorem of calculus.